# MS Access with MySQL Linked Tables not getting new record

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

So I've been trying to set my tables in MySQL to use as linked tables in a MS Access front-end file. I had these tables as MS Access tables and everything worked well. I wanted to separate the tables from this file and went and exported the tables to a MySQL DB. The exporting process works well and everything looked fine the file is running correctly.

But my data entry forms are now showing blank. I tried setting Data Entry to off and the forms show up with the data from the linked tables but I cant get them to show a new record.

I'm guessing I messed something up when setting the primary keys thing is I have this one data entry table that is working correctly and I did exactly the same to set up the primary key for that table.

All help is apreciated!

thanks!

Comment: If you follow the the docs [connector ms access](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-apptips-microsoft-access.html) and connector [link tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-linked-tables.html) linking tables is no magic. DSN setting can be deployed by registry entry or created DSN-Less via VBA.

Comment: First check linked tables for update/insert data. Check primary key in table design-view (ignore the not editable msg on open design-view). To get primary keys recognized automatic use a scheme (e.g. id, key , ...) for PK-Names and add it to 'AutoIndex on Import/Create'  in Access-Options->Object-Designers.